# Using a class for holding Figure and axis in matplotlib results with no plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a class that holds all the plotting command I commonly use to share between several projects. I created a simple class

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl


class MyPlot:

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self.figure = plt.Figure()
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)

    def test(self):
        self.ax.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
        self.show()
```

and on a different file (on a different folder):

```
from mylib.foo import MyPlot
plt = MyPlot()
plt.test()
```

But when I run this code nothing happens. If I put a print command in `test` I see the output. If I try to what is suggested [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_figure_class.html) inheriting `matplotlib.Figure` I still get no output.

If I try and print the plot to figure by adding

```
self.figure.savefig('/tmp/test.pdf')
```

I get an error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'print_figure'
```

which is even more confusing to me.

How can I create my plotter class to show the plot?

Comment: Is `self.show()` right? That should give an error. Did you mean `self.figure.show()`?

Comment: I honestly can't remember and I already written on this file. The problem still holds though, any of my attempts couldn't reach a setup where I can  create a displayable figure